# From C#, how do I call Release on a returned object that implements IStorage?

Tags: c#, com, iunknown, istorage, structured-storage

I'm reading and writing Structured Storage files from C#. To open the file i call

```
IStorage StorageInterface;

int result = StgOpenStorage(filename, null, STGM.READWRITE | STGM.SHARE_EXCLUSIVE, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out StorageInterface);
```

This works and I can access the file. I believe I need to call Release() on the Storage object to close the file. However, I don't know how to get to Release since its implemented on IUnknown.

Can I cast StorageInterface to an object that implements IUnknown and call it that way?

thanks,

john

Comment: does it Inherit from IDisposible? if not then just set the Object = null, or you can try something like this to test it `((IDisposable)YourObject).Dispose();`

Comment: It looks like IStorage doesn't inherit from IDisposable :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is derived from IUnknown.  Every COM object is derived from IUnknown.  Just call

```
 StorageInterface->Release();
```

Maybe I was hasty.  I missed the C# part...  That's how you'd do it in C++.

In C#, you should be able to call like this.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(StorageInterface);
```

Check the spelling...it's from memory.